# Transferring an array to multiple ranges

Tags: arrays, vba, variant

I have become stuck trying to solve a piece of code I thought would be very simple.
I have defined a range (2 rows, 150 columns) and transferred it to an array. I then want to use the defined array in multiple ranges (same size of 2 rows and 150 columns). I have written the following code:

```
Dim LocalArray As Variant
LocalArray = .Range("FD6781:KW6782").Value2
.Range("FD6839:KW6840,FD6955:KW6956,FD7013:KW7014,FD7071:KW7072").Value2 = LocalArray
```

The issue is that every second range defined in .range("FD6839:KW6840,FD6955:KW6956...") shows up as N/A. Hence range FD6839:KW6840 is correct while range FD6955:KW6956 is wrong.
What have I done wrong in the above code?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried assigning the ranges separately, rather than attempting all four at once? This is the first step I would take.

Comment: Yes, it works when doing them separately. I was just trying to limit the amount of code, and then I don't understand why above wouldn't work.

Comment: @Philip Good question. Solution may be looping.But real question is why it is behaving like this?

Comment: I tried it with 2 Col X 5 Row data. it is behaving weird only in 2nd, 4th ranges. if 2nd and 4th ranges are kept 5 col X 2 row, data is being weirdly restructured in 2nd and 4th ranges. .Range("A11:B15,A21:E22,A31:B35,A41:E42").Value = .Range("A1:B5").Value. _However if square shaped ranges (i.e. rows=col)  used the syntax is working correctly (I tired up to 8th range with 5X5 range)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop. Otherwise, it does seem to be related to the number of columns causing the issue. Seems odd.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim localArray(), rng As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
    localArray = ws.Range("FD6781:KW6782").Value2

     For Each rng In ws.Range("FD6839, FD6955, FD7013, FD7071")
         rng.Resize(UBound(localArray, 1), UBound(localArray, 2)) = localArray
     Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Completely agree with dropping the intermediary array.  Also, at least with sample data, there was no need for `Union`: `ws.Range("D1:E2,G1:H2,J1:K2") = arr`.

Comment: Hi both, when using that method I get the same problem as previously (i.e. every second range is wrong).

Comment: Just tried with the updated code QHarr, that works perfectly! :)
Thank you!

Comment: I recommend using `rng.Resize(UBound(localArray, 1), UBound(localArray, 2)).Value = localArray` instead of the implicit (with no `.Value`) in order to make it clear you are transfering values and not assigning references.